# ¿Cómo reducir el margen del top en una opción destacada en un menú nav?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

quiero conseguir que en mi menú, aparezcan una serie de opciones destacadas tal y como hace (por ejemplo) [www.letrame.com](https://www.letrame.com) en su menú.

Por ahora, en mi código CSS tengo esto:

```
.nav-link.highlight-box {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #f46669;
  margin: 0 0 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #f46669;
}

.nav-link.highlight-box:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f46669;
}
```

Y en mi código HTML tengo esto:

```
<header class="header py-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-8 mb-3 mb-md-0">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <img src="img/logo.svg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light justify-content-center">

                    <button class="navbar-toggler mb-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav_principal">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div id="nav_principal" class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-lg-end text-center">
                            <a href="contacto.html" class="nav-link">NOSOTROS</a>
                            <a href="blog.html" class="nav-link">BLOG</a>
                            <a href="clases.html" class="nav-link">CLASES</a>
                            <a href="galeria.html" class="nav-link">GALERÍA</a>
                            <a href="contacto.html" class="nav-link highlight-box">CONTACTO</a>
                    </div> <!-- nav_principal -->
                </nav>
            </div> <!-- col-md- 8-->
        </div> <!-- row -->
    </div>
</header>
```

Lamentablemente, me aparece el botón de CONTACTO con un margen en la parte superior que no debería estar ahí y que molesta a la vista.

¿Alguien sabe cómo arreglarlo?

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Elimina en tu CSS `padding-top: 30px;` o disminuye su tamaño. Está en la clase `.nav-link.highlight-box`

Comment: El problema, es que si lo quito el botón aparece descentrado en comparación con el resto de palabras: https://i.imgur.com/qmHLGYR.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de nada, aclarar un par de conceptos: **margin** es el espacio que separa el elemento rojo del azul, mientras que **padding** es el que separa el elemento verde del rojo.

[image: Diferencias entre padding y margin]

En tu código, lo que hace que el elemento `a` se vuelva más alto es la siguiente propiedad:

```
.nav-link.highlight-box {
  padding-top: 30px
}
```

Eliminarla hace que, entre el elemento `<div class="col-md-4 col-8 mb-3 mb-md-0"></div>` y `<div class="col-md-8"></div>` exista una separación, culpa del elemento `button`.

A no ser que se me haya pasado pensar que tengas un estilo para `button` que elimine ese espacio, la solución sería esa.

**Consejo**: utiliza los elementos en base al contexto. El camino más sencillo suele ser el más correcto:

```css
header {
  background-color: #ff3b30;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap
}

.logo {
  background-color: #4cd964;
  height: 5em;
  width: 100%
}

nav {
  background-color: #5856d6;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap
}

nav a {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #000;
  margin-right: 1em;
  padding: .25em .5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #007aff
}

nav a:last-child {
  margin-right: 0
}

.highlighted {
  background-color: #ff9500;
  color: #fff
}

.highlighted:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ff9500;
  color: #ff9500
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Nosotros</a>
    <a href="#">Blog</a>
    <a href="#">Clases</a>
    <a href="#">Galería</a>
    <a class="highlighted" href="#">Contacto</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Tu aclaración de conceptos "margin" y "padding" no es muy precisa. Te invito a que [edites tu respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/263763/edit) y agregues más información si así lo deseas.

Answer (score 1):

Solo tienes que eliminar el `padding-top: 30px;` asi:

```css
.nav-link.highlight-box {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #f46669;
  margin: 0 0 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border: 2px solid #f46669;
}

.nav-link.highlight-box:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f46669;
}
```

```html
<header class="header py-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-8 mb-3 mb-md-0">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <img src="img/logo.svg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light justify-content-center">

                    <button class="navbar-toggler mb-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav_principal">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div id="nav_principal" class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-lg-end text-center">
                            <a href="contacto.html" class="nav-link">NOSOTROS</a>
                            <a href="blog.html" class="nav-link">BLOG</a>
                            <a href="clases.html" class="nav-link">CLASES</a>
                            <a href="galeria.html" class="nav-link">GALERÍA</a>
                            <a href="contacto.html" class="nav-link highlight-box">CONTACTO</a>
                    </div> <!-- nav_principal -->
                </nav>
            </div> <!-- col-md- 8-->
        </div> <!-- row -->
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: [Posible duplicado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/263483/c%C3%B3mo-reducir-el-margen-del-top-en-una-opci%C3%B3n-destacada-en-un-men%C3%BA-nav#comment486917_263483) xD

Comment: Pero el problema, es que si lo quito el botón aparece descentrado en comparación con el resto de palabras: i.imgur.com/qmHLGYR.png

Answer (score 1):

No es un margin lo que te aparece en la parte superior, es un padding de 30 pixeles que tu le estas indicando aquí:

```
<pre> 
    .nav-link.highlight-box {
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #f46669;
    margin: 0 0 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 35px 0px 35px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    padding-top: 30px; //Esto hace que haya un espacio de 30 pixeles
    border: 2px solid #f46669;
}
</pre>
```

el padding es el espacio entre el borde de la caja y el contenido prácticamente es del borde hacia adentro, por el contrario el margin es del borde hacia afuera. 
Solo borra el

```
<code> 
   padding-top: 30px;
</code>
```

Comment: si lo quito el botón aparece descentrado en comparación con el resto de palabras: https://i.imgur.com/qmHLGYR.png

Comment: Se debe a los estilos de las clases .nav-link.highlight-box, especificamente en margin: 0 0 25px; para que estén alineados prueba con esto margin: 0 0 25 0px; o margin: 0px; esto se debe al orden en como funciona la asiganción de valor en la propiedad margin investigalo mas a fondo.

Comment: Mira los resultado haciendo la modificación en margin como te sugerí https://imgur.com/CeNzeGA